# Subcategories in Drupal 7 Contact Form

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, split, categories, contact-form

Is there a way to have subcategories on the Contact Form dropdown box in Drupal 7?

Here's the case:

I have several categories (people in this case) listed out in the dropdown box of available options for who to send the contact form email to. This is dandy, and works fine.

What I'm needing/wanting, is to be able to segment these categories into subcategories... sort of how you can do it with the Menu System in D7, creating a hierarchical drag-and-drop ordering of the menu items... is there any way anyone's seen to do that with the Categories in the Contact Page?

E.G.

Denver Office
 - John Smith
 - Alex Johnson
 - Pete Carry
Orlando Office
 - Jennifer Grand
 - Allan Jackson
 - Tim Williams

All in the same dropdown, hopefully that makes sense.

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will be possible with drupal's build in contact form. What you could do though is to use the [Webform-module](https://drupal.org/project/webform_conditional) and the [Webform Conditional](https://drupal.org/project/webform_conditional)-module. Then add multiple select lists.

1. Office

   - denver|Denver Office
   - orlando| Orlando office
2. Denver Emails

   - employee@email.com|employee name
   - ...
   - condition: field: "office", value: "denver"
3. Orlando Emails

   - employee@email.com|employee name
   - ...
   - condition: field: "office", value: "orlando"

Now, in the email option you add "Component value" and select Orlando Emails. Do that for every email list (Denver Emails and so on).

I just tested it. Works fine :-) Hope I could help.